# Counter for correct answers doesn't work for web application, VB2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, counter

I have to make my previous stand alone project into a web application. Everything works OK, for the most part, however my counter is not. The user has an option to see how many answers they are getting correct and incorrect. I copied most of my code from the original project with the exception of a few tweeks... idk what I'm not doing right.

When you input a correct answer nothing shows, but when you input a wrong answer it shows
correct:0 incorrect:1 and it doesn't change. I tried with making numCorrect and numIncorrect equal 0 as seen below... still nothing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    Protected Sub CheckButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckButton.Click
    'assign numbers to variable for calculation
    Dim correctAnswer As Integer
    Dim numCorrect As Integer = 0
    Dim numIncorrect As Integer = 0

    num1 = CInt(Val(FirstNumLabel.Text))
    num2 = CInt(Val(SecondNumLabel.Text))
    answerNum = CInt(Val(AnswerTextBox.Text))

    'calculate the correct answer
    Select Case OperationsRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex = 0
        Case True
            'addition operation
            correctAnswer = num1 + num2
        Case False
            'subtraction operation
            correctAnswer = num1 - num2
    End Select

    'tell user if their input is correct or incorrect
    'show images and messages when answer is correct
    If answerNum = correctAnswer Then
        MessageLabel.Text = "Nice Job!"
        HFaceImage.Visible = True
        SFaceImage.Visible = False
        'add count for numbers correct to summary
        numCorrect += 1
        'clear textbox for new input and focus to textbox for new
        With AnswerTextBox
            .Text = ""
            .Focus()
        End With
        'generate new random set
        Call RandomNumberGenerator()

    Else 'show image and message if answer is incorrect
        SFaceImage.Visible = True
        HFaceImage.Visible = False
        'add  count for numbers incorrect to summary 
        numIncorrect = numIncorrect + 1 '
        'display message if incorrect answer was given
        MessageLabel.Text = "Try Again!"

        'clear textbox for new input and focus to textbox 
        With AnswerTextBox
            .Text = ""
            .Focus()
        End With
        'show the number of correct and incorrect input when summaryCheckBox is checked
        If CheckBox.Checked Then
            CorrectCounterTextBox.Text = CStr(Val(numCorrect))
            IncorrectCounterTextBox.Text = CStr(Val(numIncorrect))
        Else
            CorrectCounterTextBox.Text = ""
            IncorrectCounterTextBox.Text = ""

        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the `CorrectCounterTextBox` and `IncorrectCounterTextBox` text property inside the wrong answer code block, that is why the labels don't get updated when user gave correct answer. Take it out of the `If ... Else ... End If` block like below:

```
'tell user if their input is correct or incorrect
'show images and messages when answer is correct
If answerNum = correctAnswer Then
    ' your existing code
Else 'show image and message if answer is incorrect
    SFaceImage.Visible = True
    HFaceImage.Visible = False
    'add  count for numbers incorrect to summary 
    numIncorrect = numIncorrect + 1 '
    'display message if incorrect answer was given
    MessageLabel.Text = "Try Again!"

    'clear textbox for new input and focus to textbox 
    With AnswerTextBox
        .Text = ""
        .Focus()
    End With

    ' your existing code moved out to below.
End If

'show the number of correct and incorrect input when summaryCheckBox is checked
If CheckBox.Checked Then
    CorrectCounterTextBox.Text = CStr(Val(numCorrect))
    IncorrectCounterTextBox.Text = CStr(Val(numIncorrect))
Else
    CorrectCounterTextBox.Text = ""
    IncorrectCounterTextBox.Text = ""
End If
```

PS: You might want to remove the `Dim numCorrect As Integer = 0` and `Dim numIncorrect As Integer = 0` lines at the top of your code, otherwise your counters will never get incremented. Save the counters into Session or Viewstate instead.